# How can I view SSL certificate information (the padlock popup in Chrome desktop) in Chrome Mobile?

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I'm on my Desktop Chrome, I can click on the padlock icon in the address bar and see the information about my SSL connection, like the TLS version, the certificate strength, the authority that issued the certificate, and whether there's unsecured content on the website.

Is there a way to view this information on Chrome Mobile on an Android device? In case it matters, the Android version is 4.4.2, but will likely soon change to 5.0, but if it's different for both versions, I'm interested in both methods.

I tried just tapping on the padlock icon in the address bar, but it just gives the url and "your connection is private" and an option to copy the URL.

To clarify: this is all that I see when tapping the padlock:

[image]

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

No mention of SSL version or similar stuff.

Comment: Strange; on iOS, the padlock popup shows that information.

Comment: Firefox Mobile showed [a bit more information](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VPF7H.png) than Chrome Mobile. It still doesn't show the certificate's fingerprint though, IMO the most important part to see when manually checking certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page info was simplified as the security information was cryptic for "most users":
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=302561

A subsequent issue has been raised to reimplement more detailed connection info:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425158

The latter issue has reportedly been started/assigned, so hopefully this will be fixed soon.

**EDIT:** Chrome 44 for Android has now been released (as stable). This reintroduces the connection info.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it is possible to view the certificate info again in Chrome for Android, but it would be helpful if you could explain how it can be viewed, since that is the information people are looking for when they come to this question.