# How can I view a certificate's details in Chrome on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, certificates

I recently upgraded my smartphone (from Samsung Note II running KitKat to Samsung Note 5 running Lollipop).

The new phone uses Google Chrome Browser version 46.0.2490.76 and it is great, EXCEPT I cannot figure out how to view a site's certificate details when the padlock is not green.  For example, visit http://www.papajohns.com -- this will redirect to an https:// site, but the https:// will not be green or red and hence there is no option to click for details.

[image]

The previous phone (like my other browsers) will allow me to inspect the TLS/SSL certificates (hash values, chain of trust, etc. as well as the negotiated connection details [RSA vs ECC, AES256 vs etc.)

How do I do this in Google Chrome mobile on Lollipop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view SSL certificate information (the padlock popup in Chrome desktop) in Chrome Mobile?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101472/how-can-i-view-ssl-certificate-information-the-padlock-popup-in-chrome-desktop)

Comment: Hmm, the answer there says it was fixed in v44, but this is v46.

Answer (score 8):

Click on *Green Padlock* symbol in navigation bar next to URL, click on *Details* and click on *Certificate Information* to view the Connection details.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

You can also view *DigiCert SHA2 CA*, *High Assurance CA* in the drop-down under *certificate viewer*.

EDIT:

For HTTPS websites without a Green padlock, Chrome will give an error saying 
**Your connection is not private** if you're visiting the site for the first time and you can click on the *Red Padlock* -> *Details* -> *Certificate Information*.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Also, if you're not getting the *Red padlock* when you visit the page, that's because you've clicked on *Proceeed to Webiste, I understand the risks*.

To get back that *Red padlock* you have to Clear cookies. To do that, Chrome → Settings → Privacy → Clear Browsing data → Clear Cookies and site data.

Comment: Hi, thanks I forgot to mention that I'm looking for the case where the padlock is not green (e.g. https://papajohns.com)

Comment: @digitale Clear _Cookies,site data_ you'll get the _padlock_ and can see the Certificates

Comment: I tried clearing the cookies, cache and site data, but it still doesn't work.  Try to visit http://www.papajohns.com  It will redirect to an https site.  The URL says https, there is no error but there is also no green or red icon.  I do see the green icon with websites that use an extended validation certificate.

Comment: I added an image to show what I am seeing, even after clearing the browser cache, cookies, and site data.

Comment: @digitale After clearing cache Goto `https://  papajohns.com` instead of `https://  www.papajohns.com` you'll be able to see the certificates

Comment: There are two different certificates at play here.  https:// papajohns.com is not a trusted cert because the common name is invalid (and possibly other issues).  https:// www.papajohns.com is a trusted cert by my desktop browsers and Chrome mobile seems to trust it (albeit the https prefix is not green, but it's not red either).  How do I view the details of the https:// www.papajohns.com cert from Chrome mobile?

Comment: @digitale www.papajohns.com resolves to 23.196.142.4 so you can enter `https:// 23.196.142.4` to view www.papajohns.com certificate